# Sorting a list of Strings in Alphabetical order (C)

Tags: c, string, sorting, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

Ok, here is my problem. A teacher has to randomly select a student (from the students she has) to earn a special bonus in the final score and in order to do that she puts N pieces of paper numbered from 1 to N in a bag and randomly select a number K; the award-winning student was the K-th student in the student list. The problem is that the teacher does not know which number corresponds to which student because she lost the paper that contained this information. What she knows: the names of all students, and that, their numbers, from 1 to N, are assigned according to the alphabetical order.

So I need to get the set of names that is given as input, sort them alphabetically and then provide the name of the student who won the special bonus, but I'm having trouble doing so. The program I wrote orders all the names except the first.

In addition, the following warnings appear when I run the project with Code::Blocks:

- (line 16) ISO C90 forbids array variable length 's' [-Wvla]
- (Line 13) ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong here and if there's a better way to sort the names without having the specified amount of names.

Note: the program should stop reading the input when N and K are equal to zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int n, k, i, j=0, aux, numMenorNome;
    char str[]="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", str2[]="zwyxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";

    do
    {
       scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
       struct student
       {
           char nome[21]; /*name*/
           char nomes_ordenados[21]; /*array to put the names already sorted*/
       } s[n];

       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           scanf(" %s", s[i].nome);
       }

       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       {
           aux = strcmp(str, s[i].nome); /*compares the string that would be the last in the alphabetical order ("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz") with the given names*/
           if(aux>0)
           {
               strcpy(str, s[i].nome); /*it gives me the name that comes first in alphabetical order */
               numMenorNome = i;  /* identification number of the name that was obtained */
           }
           if (i==(n-1))
           {
               strcpy(s[j].nomes_ordenados,str); 
               printf("%s\n", s[j].nomes_ordenados);
               strcpy(str, "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"); 
               strcpy(s[numMenorNome].nome, str2); 
               j++;
               i=0; /* restarts the loop in order to obtain the second name in alphabetical order, the third name, the fourth name and so on */
               if(j==n)
                    break;
           }
       }
       printf("%s\n\n", s[k-1].nomes_ordenados);

    } while (n!=0&&k!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);` seems wrong to me. How can the program know  where is the end of `n` and the beginning of `k`? And you should have a more consistent indentation/brackets style; otherwise you are making difficult the reading by people that want to help you.

Comment: The two warnings you're getting are because you need to compile your code under the C99 or later (C11) standard.

Comment: Side-note: Are you allowed to use `qsort`? Because this problem is much simpler [with `qsort` to sort the names](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort), so you can just directly index to find the Kth student. You could also skip this whole "struct with two different names in it for no good reason" schtick and just store an array (variable length or dynamically allocated) of `char*`, sort said array ([`strcmp` already exists as a sort function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)) and you're there.

Comment: @sergiol no problem with that, by default most format specifiers will skip whitespaces before reading the value, so just put some spaces between them

Answer (score 7):

Sorting an array of strings are real simple. Just use `qsort` and the existing compare function (i.e. `strcmp`)

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMES 5
#define NAME_LEN 10

void print_names(char names[][NAME_LEN])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<NAMES; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", names[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char names[NAMES][NAME_LEN] = { "xxx", "uuu", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb" };

    print_names(names);
    printf("---------------------------------\n");

    qsort(names, NAMES, NAME_LEN, strcmp);

    print_names(names);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm as well!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *names[] = { "xxx", "uuu", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb" };
    char *tmp;
    int i = 0, j;
    for(i; names[i]; i++) {
        for(j = 0; names[j]; j++) {
            if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]) < 0) {
                tmp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j];
                names[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; names[i]; i++) printf("%s\n", names[i]);
    return 0;
}
```