# Name sorting in C

Tags: c, string, sorting

Bellow a program I've made to sort names like a mobile phone does i.e sort the list with the first letter alphabetically, then with in that sorted list again sort the list with the second letters alphabetically and so on. If the two names have same letters with a or more than one extra letter added in one name then that name will appear below the other name. But I couldn't find whats wrong in this code. Please help. I've tried to make it as much as readable as possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int check_counter=0;
    int col_no=0;

    int in_check(int *check, int element_no, int total_element)
    {
         int i;

         for(i=0; i<total_element; i++)
         {
              if(check[i]==element_no)
              return 1;
         }

         return 0;
    }


    int bubble_sort_chars(char **arr, int len_of_arr, int *check)
    {
         int main_counter,sub_counter1,sub_counter2;
         char char1, char2;
         char *temp;

         for(main_counter=len_of_arr-1,check_counter=0; main_counter>0; main_counter--)//Decreasing main counter untill it indicates the position of the second element
         {
              for(sub_counter1=0,sub_counter2=1; sub_counter1<main_counter; sub_counter1++,sub_counter2++)//Increasing the sub counter for a specific value of main counter untill it indicates the immidiate previous value of main counter
              {
                  //Check if the sub_counter 1 and 2 belongs to check[] or it's a space or not
                  if( in_check(check,sub_counter1,check_counter+1)==1 || *(*(arr+sub_counter1)+col_no)==' ' )
                  sub_counter1++;
                  else if( in_check(check,sub_counter2,check_counter+1)==1 || *(*(arr+sub_counter2)+col_no)==' ' )
                  sub_counter2++;

                  //If the sub_counter element is null then putting the position the the string in the check()
                  if(*(*(arr+sub_counter2)+col_no)==0)
                   {
                        check[check_counter]=sub_counter2;
                        check_counter++;
                        sub_counter2++;
                        continue;
                   }

                   char1 = *(*(arr+sub_counter1)+col_no); char2= *(*(arr+sub_counter2)+col_no);
                   //Making the first character element of each string to upper case if it's lower case
                   if( char1>=97 && char1<=122 ) char1 -= 32;
                   if( char2>=97 && char2<=122 ) char2 -= 32;

                   if(char1>char2)
                   {
                        temp = *(arr+sub_counter2); 
                        *(arr+sub_counter2) = *(arr+sub_counter1);
                        *(arr+sub_counter1) = temp; 
                   }
              }
         }

         return check_counter;
    }


    void alphabet_sort(char **arr, int len_of_arr)
    {
         int main_counter,start_pos,ch;
         char char1,char2;
         int check[len_of_arr];

         ch=bubble_sort_chars(arr,len_of_arr,check);
         if( ch == len_of_arr-1 || ch == len_of_arr )
         return;

         for(main_counter=0; main_counter<len_of_arr-1; main_counter++)
         {
              start_pos=main_counter;
              char1 = *(*(arr+main_counter)+col_no);
              if( char1>=97 && char1<=122 ) char2 -= 32;//Making the first character element of the string to upper case if it's lower case and putting it in char2

              while(*(*(arr+main_counter)+col_no)==char1 || *(*(arr+main_counter)+col_no)==char2)//Counting where the alphabet ends (char1 or char2) in the sorted list of first element characters
              main_counter++;
              main_counter--;

              col_no++;
              alphabet_sort(arr+start_pos, main_counter-start_pos );
         }

         return;
    }

    int main()
    {
         char *name[]=
         {
              "A",
              "AB",
              "Al",
              "ABc",
              "abk",
              "Zap",
              "abce",
              "Abv",
              "abcp",
              "zop",
              "zzz",
              "P",
              "Zap",
              "Abcd",
              "Zoo",
              "A",
              "c"
         };


         alphabet_sort(name,17);

         int i;
         for(i=0; i<17; i++)
         {
              printf("%s\n", name[i]);
         }

         getch();
    }
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a list of Strings in Alphabetical order (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033310/sorting-a-list-of-strings-in-alphabetical-order-c)

Comment: nothing...its probably calling the function alphabet sort infinitely and thus giving error

Comment: suggest using the function: `strcmp()` (as exposed via the header file: `string.h`) to sort pairs of strings

Comment: @user3629249 hmm oky.. firstly i have to identify why its giving error after running. I could'n figure it out

Comment: @user3629249 it is passes from main to alphabet_sort....it indicates the length of the array of pointer to strings

Comment: regarding: `alphabet_sort(name,17);` and other statements using `17`:  a much better method (and much less error prone) is: `alphabet_sort(name, sizeof( name ) / sizeof( char* ) );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int i;
         for(i=0; i<17; i++)`  It is best to limit the scope of variables.  Therefore, a better way to write this would be: `for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( name ) / sizeof( char* ); i++ )`

Comment: [bubble sort algorithm](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort)  which is sorting integers, but is an easy modification to sort strings (via the pointers to the strings)

Comment: regarding: `char1 = *(*(arr+main_counter)+col_no);
              if( char1>=97 && char1<=122 ) char2 -= 32;`  shouldn't the variable `char2` be initialized before subtracting 32 from it?   BTW: the header file: `ctype.h` contains `tolower()` which will take any byte value and output (if upper case) the lower case value, otherwise doing nothing

Comment: @user3629249 can u please explain how the above expression `sizeof( alphabet_sort ) / sizeof( char* )` can give the size of the array name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203404/discussion-between-abhirup-bakshi-and-user3629249).

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
for( main_counter=0; main_counter<len_of_arr-1; main_counter++ )
{
    start_pos=main_counter;
    char1 = *(*(arr+main_counter)+col_no);
    if( char1>=97 && char1<=122 ) 
        char2 -= 32;//Making the first character element of the string to upper case if it's lower case and putting it in char2

    while( *(*( arr+main_counter ) + col_no ) == char1 || *(*( arr+main_counter ) + col_no ) == char2 )//Counting where the alphabet ends (char1 or char2) in the sorted list of first element characters
        main_counter++;

    main_counter--;

    col_no++;
    alphabet_sort(arr+start_pos, main_counter-start_pos );
}
```

the result of `main_counter-start_pos` is either 0 or -1

Comment: how? the starting_pos stores the value of the position of the string for a particular letter's first appearance in the partially sorted string list and main_counter increases as the loop runs. when a string comes where in that position of the string, identified by col_no, there is an other letter the loop stops and main_counter is assigned to that "new letter's first appearance string" position. Then why main_counter - starting_pos only gives 0 or -1 and not other value? BTW why it gives -1 as main_counter is always greater than or equal to starting_pos?